# Symfony2 && mongodb simple reference

Tags: mongodb, symfony

he guys,

i want to make a simple reference on mongodb documents using symfony2.

i have this two documents and want to store picture references into the requests document. it works for me, if i have only the picture ids in the requests document.

so i need the follow:

can everyone change the document files and make and extends the custum call to get all pictures as object from the requests (picture array)?

my original files:

Document Pictures:

```
<?php

namespace TestBundle\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="TestBundle\Repository\RequestsRepository")
 */
class Requests
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $title;

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

Document Pictures:

```
<?php

namespace TestBundle\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="TestBundle\Repository\PicturesRepository")
 */
class Pictures
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $filename;

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setFilename($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->filename;
    }
}
```

My Basic Calls:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$request = $dm->getRepository('TestBundle:Requests')->find($requestId);
```

To my tests:

i added in the requests document the follow:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Pictures",cascade={"persist"},simple="true")
 */
protected $pictures = array();
public function setPictures($pictures)
{
    $this->pictures[] = $pictures;
}

public function getPictures()
{
    return $this->pictures;

}
```

and added pictures like this:

```
$dm     = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$photo   = $dm->getRepository('TestBundle:Pictures')->find($photoId);

$dm1 = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$request = $dm1->getRepository('TestBundle:Requests')->find($requestId);

$request->setPictures($photo);
$dm1->flush();
```

this works - but i cannot get the pictures by loading the document.

my code to load:

```
$dm1 = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$request = $dm1->getRepository('TestBundle:Requests')->find($requestId);

$pictures = $request->getPictures();

foreach($pictures as $picture)
{
    print $picture->getId();         
}
```

THIS WILL NOT WORK. i become the follow error:

> Fatal error: Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Proxy\ProxyFactory::getProxy():
>   Failed opening required
>   '.../app/cache/dev/doctrine/odm/mongodb/Proxies/_*CG*_TestBundleDocumentPictures.php'
>   (include_path='.:.../library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear') in
>   ..../test/vendor/doctrine-mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php
>   on line 100

**thanks, jan**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the error:

In the deps file i have the following lines:

```
[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.1.4

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.1.7

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.1.7
```

After updating them to:

```
[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.2.1

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.2.1

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.2.1
```

And doing `php bin/vendors update` the references will work again

Answer (score 0):

First off you only need to call doctrine one time in $dm your overloading your resources and thats bad practice. One function, one Doctrine call. Secondly, you need a $dm->persist($request) and then $dm->flush().  Create a OnetoOne between your Documents and then make $pictures an Doctrine Array Collection.  Then set a picture like you tried, then  make a smiple query and call $request->getPicture()->getId().

Comment: hey dave, you are right - the overloading is super bad and the persist call are in my code implemented. but when i use a recerenceOne, the code sucks by this call and gives the same error $dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
        $request = $dm->getRepository('WunschbildBundle:Requests')->find($requestId);